# Delete input field from Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I delete an input field from Excel 2007?

Note that copying the content of the page without selecting the input is not an acceptable answer.

[image]

Comment: How has been this input field created? Is it a form control? In this case it is easy to get rid of it over "Development" tools...

Comment: @duDE  Created by "copy and pasting" from a website.  Where is "Development" tools?

Comment: So try to go to "Developer Tools" and get a rid of this control: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291073

Comment: @duDE  Thanks.  The solution was to add "Developer Tools", then toggle "Design Mode", and then I was able to select and delete it.  Seems like a lot of work for something that should be more intuitive!

Comment: You are welcome! If you want, write your solution as an answer and mark it as "solved" ...

Comment: @duDE  I figured I would give you a chance first if you wanted to.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user1032531](https://superuser.com/users/234013/user1032531) wrote, the solution was to add "Developer Tools", then toggle "Design Mode", and then to select and delete it: [How to use the forms controls on a worksheet in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291073)